# What does "import the individual SDK components you intend to use" in firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a signup page using react with firebase for the backend and this is the error in the console.

````
When deploying Firebase apps to production, it is advisable to only import
the individual SDK components you intend to use.

For the module builds, these are available in the following manner
(replace <PACKAGE> with the name of a component - i.e. auth, database, etc):

CommonJS Modules:
const firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/<PACKAGE>');

ES Modules:
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';

Typescript:
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/<PACKAGE>';```
````

Answer (score 1):

To simplify it, when you use `require("firebase");` or `import firebase from "firebase";`, you import [EVERYTHING](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#namespace). More often than not you don't use every library listed below.

For testing, importing from the root package `"firebase"` is fine, but when you deploy to production/compile your app, you shouldn't use it - which is what this error is saying.

**Remember:** Import what you need and don't import what you don't.

```js
import firebase from "firebase";
```

is effectively the same as

```js
import firebase from "firebase/app";  // Analytics
import "firebase/analytics";          // Analytics
import "firebase/auth"                // Authentication
import "firebase/firestore"           // Cloud Firestore
import "firebase/functions"           // Cloud Functions for Firebase Client SDK
import "firebase/messaging"           // Cloud Messaging
import "firebase/storage"             // Cloud Storage
import "firebase/performance"         // Performance Monitoring
import "firebase/database"            // Realtime Database
import "firebase/remoteConfig"        // Remote Config
```

In most cases for React, you want to import from the [React Native Firebase (RNFB)](https://rnfirebase.io) packages like [`"@react-native-firebase/app"`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/app), [`"@react-native-firebase/database"`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/database) and so on.

To get access to the underlying `firebase` library for the RNFB libs, you would use:

```js
import firebase from "@react-native-firebase/app";
// or 
import database, { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/database";
```